# При постоянной проверки пинга или скачивании фалов с помощью WebClient зависает интернет

Tags: c#, .net

Есть класс, который выводит информацию о сервере. Я использую этот класс для проверки пинга какого-нибудь сервера. При нажатии на кнопку проверить пинг больше 150 раз интернет зависает полностью.
Так же имеется другой класс, который скачивает файлы с интернета с очередью и после определенного количества скачиваний интернет полностью зависает и загрузка файла останавливается.
Через несколько секунд, если программа не подключается к сети, интернет снова начинает работать, но на определенное время. Чем больше ждешь после зависания тем больше времени интернет работает без зависаний. Но стоит дойти до определенного количества подключений или скачиваний чего-либо как интернет снова зависает. Сперва я думал, что виновен класс, что он неправильно создан и все подобное, но сам создав функцию скачивания фала убедился в том, что не класс виноват, но и мои файлы не скачиваются. 
Никак не могу решить эту проблему.

Вот код класса для который выводит информацию о сервере

```
class SampQuery
{
    IPAddress serverIp;
    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;
    Socket svrConnect;

    string IP;
    ushort Port;
    bool bDebug = false;

    DateTime TransmitMS = new DateTime();
    DateTime ReceiveMS = new DateTime();

    Ping Sping = new Ping();

    public SampQuery(string ip, ushort port, char packet_type, bool console_debug)
    {
        //_hostname = ip;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        try
        {
            serverIp = new IPAddress(IPAddress.Parse(ip).GetAddressBytes());
            serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIp, port);

            svrConnect = new Socket(serverEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
            {
                SendTimeout = 500,
                ReceiveTimeout = 2500
            };
            IP = ip;
            Port = port;
            bDebug = console_debug;
            if (bDebug)
                Console.Write("Соединение к "/*Connecting to*/ + ip + ":" + port + Environment.NewLine);

            try
            {
                using (stream)
                {
                    using (writer)
                    {
                        string[] szSplitIP = IP.ToString().Split('.');

                        writer.Write("SAMP".ToCharArray());

                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt16(szSplitIP[0])));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt16(szSplitIP[1])));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt16(szSplitIP[2])));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt16(szSplitIP[3])));

                        writer.Write(Port);
                        writer.Write(packet_type);

                        if (bDebug) Console.Write("Передающий пакет '"/*Transmitting Packet*/ + packet_type + "'" + Environment.NewLine);

                        TransmitMS = DateTime.Now; // To get ping (ms to reach back & forth to the svr)
                    }
                }
                svrConnect.SendTo(stream.ToArray(), serverEndPoint);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (bDebug) Console.Write($"Не удалось получить пакет: {e}"); //Console.Write("Failed to receive packet:", e);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (bDebug) Console.Write($"Не удалось подключиться к IP: {e}"); //Console.Write("Failed to connect to IP:", e);
        }
        GC.Collect();
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dictionary<string, string> dData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> Read(bool flushdata = false)
    {
        try
        {
            serverIp = new IPAddress(IPAddress.Parse(IP).GetAddressBytes());
            serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIp, Port);

            EndPoint rawPoint = serverEndPoint;

            byte[] szReceive = new byte[3402];

            svrConnect.ReceiveFrom(szReceive, ref rawPoint);
            svrConnect.Close();

            ReceiveMS = DateTime.Now;
            if (flushdata)
                dData.Clear();

            string ping = ReceiveMS.Subtract(TransmitMS).Milliseconds.ToString(); // Зависало при подключении больше 190
            //Get_Server_Ping();





            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(szReceive);
            BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            using (stream)
            {
                using (read)
                {
                    read.ReadBytes(10);

                    switch (read.ReadChar())
                    {
                        case 'i':
                            dData.Add("password", Convert.ToString(read.ReadByte()));
                            dData.Add("players", Convert.ToString(read.ReadInt16()));
                            dData.Add("maxplayers", Convert.ToString(read.ReadInt16()));
                            dData.Add("hostname", new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadInt32())));
                            dData.Add("gamemode", new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadInt32())));
                            dData.Add("language", new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadInt32())));
                            dData.Add("ping", ping.ToString());   //Дополнительный ключ для более удобного использования
                            break;

                        case 'r':
                            for (int i = 0, iRules = read.ReadInt16(); i < iRules; i++)
                                dData.Add(new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadByte())), new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadByte())));
                            break;

                        case 'c':
                            for (int i = 0, iPlayers = read.ReadInt16(); i < iPlayers; i++)
                                dData.Add(new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadByte())), Convert.ToString(read.ReadInt32()));
                            break;

                        case 'd':
                            for (int i = 0, iTotalPlayers = read.ReadInt16(); i < iTotalPlayers; i++)
                            {
                                string id = Convert.ToString(read.ReadByte());
                                dData.Add(id + ".name", new string(read.ReadChars(read.ReadByte())));
                                dData.Add(id + ".score", Convert.ToString(read.ReadInt32()));
                                dData.Add(id + ".ping", Convert.ToString(read.ReadInt32()));
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'p':
                            dData.Add("ping", ping.ToString());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException SockEx)
        {
            if (bDebug)
                Console.Write("Проблема с чтением данных ({0})" + Environment.NewLine/*There's been a problem reading the data*/, SockEx.ErrorCode);
        }
        return dData;
```

Comment: Пару рекомендаций: 1) нужен рефакторинг, например зачем нужна вот эта смешная операция `IP = ip;   Port = port;  bDebug = console_debug;` ? Такую 3-х этажную вложенность нужно разбить на вызовы небольших приватных методов. 2) запустите отладку с условием остановки после 120-130 циклов пинга, а дальше вручную попробуйте найти место затыка.

Comment: Еще может быть, что ваши пинги бегут очень быстро друг за другом, что перегружает запрашиваемый сервер. Может быть у вашего хостера стоит защита от атак на отказ в обслуживании и она срабатывает после определенного количества последовательных однотипных запросов к серверу.

Comment: _Еще может быть, что ваши пинги бегут очень быстро друг за другом_
Сам сервер отвечает на любое количество запросов через стандартное приложение.
Есть такое, ставить в ожидание. 
Создал таймер на 2 сек, который выполняет один метод, в котором создается поток, в котором создается объект класса и там уже запрашиваю все возможную информацию от сервера.
Поставил на выполение и заснул сам на пару минут, ничего не зависло. Но что-то тут неправильно. Я же не могу теперь файлы(каждый файл)скачивать допустим только через 2 секунды.

Comment: С другой программы я быстро нажимаю на обновление сервера и все быстро работает и не зависает. Эти api от этого сервиса.
Моя же программа зависает и дело значит не в сервере.
Тем более моя программа зависает даже при обычной загрузке файлов с сайта